# automatic cookie bar pure css works fine but need delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I added this pure css cookie bar to my website and all works fine, the only problem is that when you enter in the site, you can see FIRST the cookie bar, AND the cookie bar go up and go down at the end.

How can see my cookie bar only go down when i enter in my site, i thought to change de thenimation delay, add set time out .... but nothing change !!

here is the original codepen and you can see what i want to change in it

```
    www.codepen.io/natewiley/pen/uGtcD
```

HERE IS MY CODE

```
<input class="checkbox-cb" id="checkbox-cb" type="checkbox" />
<div class="cookie-bar">


<div class="message">
This website uses cookies to give you an incredible experience. By using 
this website you agree to the
<div class="buttoncookies-container">
<a style="letter-spacing: 1px;" class="buttoncookies" id="modalcookieslinken" onclick="toggleOverlay()">terms</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
This website uses cookies, 
<div class="buttoncookies-container">
<a style="letter-spacing: 1px;" class="buttoncookies" id="modalcookiesshortlink" onclick="toggleOverlay()">
learn more
</a>
</div>
</div>


<label for="checkbox-cb" class="close-cb">X</label>
</div>

</div>
```

HERE IS MY CSS

```
.cookie-bar { z-index:9996; position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: auto; padding: 20px;  line-height:20px; text-align: center; background: #d2c6af; transition: .8s; animation: slideIn .8s; animation-delay: .8s; display: inline-block; }

.mobile { display: none; }

@keyframes slideIn { 0% { transform: translateY(-1000px); }  100% { transform: translateY(0); } }

.close-cb { border: none; background: none; position: absolute; display: inline-block; right: 20px; top: 10px; cursor: pointer; }

.close-cb:hover { color:#fff;; }

.checkbox-cb { display: none;}  

#checkbox-cb:checked + .cookie-bar { transform: translateY(-1000px); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the line in css
      animation-delay: .8s;
will give you the result

Make the animation last longer.

```
animation: slideIn 4s;
```

Plus add some trick to animation flow:

```
0% {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
50% {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
100% {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: it works fine and if I want to see it not directly, for example after 2 seconds ?

Comment: perfect mister ;D